# Confusion regarding the enable option in Google API

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

in my account the google drive api is disabled but still when I authenticate a thirdparty app using oauth2.0 it can access my drive files. Then what is the use of this enable api.
[image]

Comment: can i have a link to the page you just posted a picture of then i can be more specific with my anwser.

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=giri-3453

Answer (score 2):

[Cloud developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) is a place for developers to create applications.  when you create a new application you must decide which APIs will be used by that application.

> I authenticate a third party app using oauth2.0 it can access my drive files

Unless you are the developer of the third party application setting this will not have any effect on what applications created by other developers can do with your account.  If you dont want them accessing your drive account then dont install any third party applications that request permission to access your drive account.

Comment: So what you are saying is that, only if I am developing an application locally these api restrictions has effect. If for eg: a public app being registered in google, can access any data based on the scope even if this api has been enabled or disabled in my google account.

Comment: Yes any third party developer can create an application that will allow them to access your data.  Its up to you to not install the application if you dont want then to access it.  You cant disable this in your google account.

Comment: How to register a google app publicly, if so should I give the scopes needed to be used by the app at the time of registration itself.

Comment: you create your app in the page you just linked.  When its ready you release it.    When you request access of users they will be asked to consent to the scopes of your application.